# Inspect request body within a spring security filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-rest

Basic Spring Security is great as it comes with WebSecurity (preventing malformed URLs) along with setting up authentication and authorization.

As part of authenticating my web request, the digest of the request body needs to be verified against the digest value passed in the http header. Setting up the Spring Security filter, forces my auth filter to process a firewalled request. The firewalled request doesn't seem to expose the request body to the filter.

What is the correct way to set up the Spring Security filter so that I can inspect the request body?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

In Spring Security there are many filter classes built in for to be extended and used for specific purposes. As in my experience most of (or all of them) have methods with overloads which have access to,

`HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response`

as method arguments, so that those can be used inside the method. 
When the filter class is met with any request, these variables are then populated with related data thus the code inside the methods output as expected.